# A process with multiple possible roots/causes

Tags: nouns

How do you call a **process/phenomenon** that **can** have **multiple causes**? For example, a disease can result from many factors (not necessarily their interplay but instead when different causes manifest in different age/genetic groups). I am seeking for a **noun** (if not, an adjective), primarily in the context of studying such a phenomenon (a "nightmare" doesn't work) - a "multiroot", a "bundle" but more scientific.

*Example:*

- The mechanism of the process is still debated and may be a
  multiroot (=multiple mechanisms can operate simultaneously to cause
  the process).

Comment: It would really help if you could use it in a sentence.  Just about everything has multiple causes.

Comment: [This Stroke Journal  article](http://stroke.ahajournals.org/content/43/8/2207) article seems to use 'multicause' as a common premodifier.

Comment: According to scientists from Berkley, "shoelace knot failure" is triggered by a "complex interaction of forces": http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-39575454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **multifactorial** seems appropriate for an adjective.

> having or stemming from a number of different causes or influences:
>   *Some medical researchers regard cancer as a multifactorial disease.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multifactorial

Although often used in medicine, the definition is certainly broad enough to apply to other fields. It's also a technical term, so it seems like it could apply to the question as you described it.

Coming up with a noun is difficult.  I keep thinking of **manifold**, but I can't find a definition that's abstract enough to apply to your request for a general term.

Per Wikipedia, one definition:

> A manifold is a wide and/or bigger pipe, or channel, into which smaller pipes or channels lead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold_(fluid_mechanics)

You could appropriate that term to describe systems or processes as well, but I can't say that it has a prescribed definition that applies precisely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Multidetermined* and *overdetermined* are both adjectives.

**multidetermined**

> Determined by multiple factors. (Wiktionary)

**overdetermined**

> having more than one determining psychological factor :  affording an
>   outlet for more than a single wish or need an overdetermined dream
>   symbol (MW)

Answer (score 0):

**Contributory Causes** appears to be the common term for those causes that, when taken together, describe multiple causes that taken individually would not produce a given result.

Under the heading of *[Necessary and Sufficient Causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Necessary_and_sufficient_causes)*, a Wikipedia article describes *contributory causes* as

> A factor that is a contributory cause is one amongst several co-occurrent causes...In general, a factor that is a contributory cause is not sufficient, because it is by definition accompanied by other causes, which would not count as causes if it were sufficient. For the specific effect, a factor that is on some occasions a contributory cause might on some other occasions be sufficient, but on those other occasions it would not be merely contributory.